# Ada function "+" "*" "-" "/"

Tags: function, operator-overloading, ada

I have a question about function, with Ada.

I look a code about rational number, and I don't understand how the program is running.

FOR EXAMPLE:

```
This is rational.ads

function "+"(R1,R2: Rationnel) return Rationnel;
function "-"(R1,R2: Rationnel) return Rationnel;
function "-"(R : in Rationnel) return Rationnel;
function "*"(R1,R2: Rationnel) return Rationnel;
function "/"(R1,R2: Rationnel) return Rationnel;
```

This is `rational.adb`

```
function "+" (R1,R2: Rationnel) return Rationnel is
    N,D : Integer;
begin
    N:= R1.num *R2.den + R2.num*R1.den;
    D:= R1.den*R2.Den;
    return Simplification ((N,D));
end "+";

function "-" (R1,R2: Rationnel) return Rationnel is
    N : Integer; 
    D : Positive;
begin
    N:= R1.num *R2.den - R2.num*R1.den;
    D:= R1.den*R2.Den;
    return Simplification ((N,D));
end "-";
```

The realization is not a problem for me. 
I don't understand the following line

```
R1,R2,R3 : rationnel;
R1 := R2 + R3;
```

How is it possible to use the function "+", with this order of arguments?

[A+B : Argument1 = A, Argument2 = B]

And not for example : `R1 := +(R2,R3)`, as we usually do with function.

I hope I was clear enough and that my English was not too unbearable to read ;-)

Comment: This is called "operator overloading"; I don't know how it works in Ada specifically, but knowing that term might help you find the full answer.

Comment: Code is much easier to read if it's indented properly. I've fixed it for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're dealing with is the difference between functional notation and infix notation.
Given:

```
Function "+"(Left, Right: Rational) return Rational;
```

we know that the above can be called like this:

```
some_value:= "+"( Left => R1, Right => R2 );
```

this is actually the same as:

```
-- In infix-notation R1 is on the Left, and R2 is on the Right.
some_value:= R1 + R2;
```

Comment: @user3369462 Note that when you use function notation to call `"+"`, you need the quote marks.  Also, if necessary, you can qualify it with a package name or other names, e.g. `Rational."+"(Left=>R1, Right=>R2)`.  Sometimes that's necessary.  But you can only qualify it when you call it like this, not when used in infix notation.